# Why is there an error in my integer array after declaring an integer in my main function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am trying out some codes that is based on finding all possible combinations that add up to a integer's value that is declared in the main function. However, the problem is when I call the function "findCombinations(n);", it gives an error at "int arr[n];". That is the only line which has an error which is stopping me from running the program. If you know of a solution, do let me know.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void findCombinationsUtil(int arr[], int index,
    int num, int reducedNum)
{
    // Base condition 
    if (reducedNum < 0)
        return;

    // If combination is found, print it 
    if (reducedNum == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            cout << arr[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
        return;
    }

    // Find the previous number stored in arr[] 
    // It helps in maintaining increasing order 
    int prev = (index == 0) ? 1 : arr[index - 1];

    // note loop starts from previous number 
    // i.e. at array location index - 1 
    for (int k = prev; k <= num; k++)
    {
        // next element of array is k 
        arr[index] = k;

        // call recursively with reduced number 
        findCombinationsUtil(arr, index + 1, num,
            reducedNum - k);
    }
}

void findCombinations(int n)
{
    // array to store the combinations 
    // It can contain max n elements 
    int arr[n];

    //find all combinations 
    findCombinationsUtil(arr, 0, n, n);
}
int main()
{
    int n = 10;
    findCombinations(n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would make sense to tell us what the error is exactly.

Comment: Ignoring the fact that `int arr[n];` is not valid in C++, what do you think is stored in the array when you first print it in `findCombinationsUtil`?

Comment: The dimension of arrays must be known at compile-time in C++. You could replace the line with `std::vector<int> arr(n);`  and the first argument to the subsequent function will be `&arr[0]`. Or pass the `10` as a template parameter

Comment: the error is at the function called void findCombinations(int n) at the part which says int arr[n], the "n" in the array has a red underline which I do not understand why.

Comment: Yes, but what is the error? Cut and paste the exact error into the question.

Comment: @M.M Hi sir, do u mind writing the code for exactly what u meant, I am quite lost. Do I have to use pointers or templates?

Comment: @kaylum the error states that "the expression did not evaluate to a constant" and "the expression must have a constant value"

Comment: Please put such critical info into the question and not in comments.

Comment: Without looking at your code, copying and pasting to http://cpp.sh/ seems to compile and work cpp.sh/4ogp6  . Please edit the question and add the error you're getting, as well as which compiler you're using. Could it be that you're treating warnings as errors?

Comment: @EyalD the site clearly uses non-standard extensions

Comment: @EyalD Unfortunately, GCC allows its non-standard extensions (like Variable Length Array) by default. The error can be reproduced in MSVC, which is more standard compliant in this matter.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thanks, that's what I was aiming for :)

Comment: @EyalD gcc by default uses VLA extension which does dynamic allocation magic in this case. It's not reglamented how that extension works in C++ context, it's a C feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C-style array dimensions must be known at compile-time in Standard C++.

You can make `n` be a compile-time function parameter like this:

```
template<int n>
void findCombinations()
{
    // array to store the combinations 
    // It can contain max n elements 
    int arr[n];

    //find all combinations 
    findCombinationsUtil(arr, 0, n, n);
}

int main()
{
    const int n = 10;
    findCombinations<n>();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Upping this because in this context it works too and is the simplest if unfaithful change. It breaks as soon as we get asked to allow user to input value of `n`.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/:

> NOTE: The elements field within square brackets [], representing the number of elements in the array, must be a constant expression, since arrays are blocks of static memory whose size must be determined at compile time, before the program runs.

While some compilers will allow it, you should avoid dynamic size arrays.

Here are a few options:

1. If the size of the array will always be 10, initiate it to hard-coded const 10.
2. Use std::shared_ptr to an array pointer:
   std::shared_ptr pArray;
   pArray=std::make_shared(n)
3. Use std::vector to dynamically allocate the size. (IMHO this is the preferred option).
4. use c-style pointers (IMHO should only be used as last resort)
5. Template class (wasteful, as it created and compiles many instances of the same function)

Answer (score 1):

Type of variable arr must be known at compile time. If you need storage of variable size, you have to allocate it.

Possible alternative (one of many)

```
#include <vector>
void findCombinations(int n)
{
    // array to store the combinations 
    // It can contain max n elements 
    std::vector<int> arr(n); // allocate  n elements

    //find all combinations 
    findCombinationsUtil( &*arr.begin(), 0, n, n);
}
```

if compiler at least partially complies to C++11 e.g. it's late gcc 4.6 or higher or VS2010 and higher, then there is method `data()` that returns pointer to internal storage. But better to rewrite, templatize or overload `findCombinationsUtil`  to use a container or iterator

Comment: Why get an iterator, only to deference and reference it again? 
You can pass the vector by non-const reference

Comment: @EyalD no argument there. No particular reason other than preserving the code